# OpenID: Trying to Get Email Address from Google OP

Tags: c#, openid, dotnetopenauth

I’m using dotnetopenauth 3.2 to implement Openid and can’t figure out how to get Google to pass the email address in the Claims Response. I know that Google doesn’t support simple registration, but I can’t determine what they do support.

Caveat to this question is that I just started learning OpenID and I know I don’t have a solid grasp on the specification which I think is leading to my confusion.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I posted a question on [Goolge's Federated Log API group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/browse_thread/thread/5521cae736698091#) and was told to use [Attribute exchange](http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.3/html/N_DotNetOpenAuth_OpenId_Extensions_AttributeExchange.htm).

Below is the code for [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/).

***Please don't use this code in production. This is for illustration purposes only!***

The Request:

```
using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
{
    IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(openidurl);

    var fetch = new FetchRequest();
    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
    request.AddExtension(fetch);

    // Send your visitor to their Provider for authentication.
    request.RedirectToProvider();
}
```

The Response:

```
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var response = openid.GetResponse();
if (response != null)
{
    switch (response.Status)
    {
        case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
        {
            var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
            string email = string.Empty();
            if (fetch != null)
            {
                email =  fetch.GetAttributeValue(
                    WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            }

            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
                response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great. Would you happen to know how to get the provider name as well (aside from analyzing the response)?

Comment: Do you mean the claimed ID?

case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
{
    string identifier = response.ClaimedIdentifier;
}

Comment: I think he was talking about the actual friendly name of the provider ie: "Google" "Facebook" w/out having to parse the response.

Comment: With the help of the above code you can also get user first name and last name - thanks zaffiro

Comment: fetch is always null for me, any idea why/

Comment: @ShawnMclean it depends on the provider and whether they support the request. Try var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>(); as well.

Comment: And how would u add optional attributes those are not required..?

Comment: Oh I found it.. `AddOptional`

Answer (score 1):

When I try to get Full Name the response is null,please provide a solution to get the Full name,
This post is really help ful
Thank.
My sample code like this.

```
var fetch = new FetchRequest();
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Company.CompanyName);
            //fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);

            request.AddExtension(fetch);
```

**And**

```
if (fetch != null)
         {
             email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
             name = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
             company = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Company.CompanyName);
         }
```