# How do I get the username using DotNetOpenAuth with Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that uses DotNetOpenAuth as authentication provider. How do I get the username (or email address) when the user logs using https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?

```
switch (response.Status)
    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
        string userOpenId = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
        break;
(...)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301200/openid-trying-to-get-email-address-from-google-op

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope your `userOpenId` local variable isn't what you're using for a username, because as the property you're assigning it from is aptly named, it's for display only.  You should only use `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` for usernames.

That aside, you can get the Google email address (you can never get the username) by sending a FetchRequest for email marked as a required attribute.  This has been asked many times already, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301200/openid-trying-to-get-email-address-from-google-op).

Comment: This might be a newbie question, Andrew Arnott, but why can you get the Google email address but not the username (and what is the difference?) I thought they were one and the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a difference between username and email address when it comes to Google. But I think users are allowed to change their primary email address on their Google account (especially if it's not linked to a Gmail account), and if you had been using the Google email address as if it were a username, the user would then lose access to their account with your web app. That's just one reason why using the user identifier intended by the protocol (claimed_id) is so important.