# OpenID on Google not returning anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gmail, openid, yahoo-mail

For some reason, the following code does not return anything:

```
string alias = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
var sreg = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
if (sreg != null && sreg.MailAddress != null) 
{
    alias = sreg.MailAddress.User;
}
if (sreg != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sreg.Email))
{
    alias = sreg.Email;
}
if (sreg != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sreg.FullName)) 
{
    alias = sreg.FullName;
}
```

I was hoping I can get the Email from Yahoo or Google, but sreg just return null whichever provider I have chosen.

I saw some of other posts that this code should return an e-mail at least, but for me, it does not, please assist.

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenID: Trying to Get Email Address from Google OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301200/openid-trying-to-get-email-address-from-google-op)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that what you add the email address to ClaimsRequest with the *required* flag set to true.

You must also ensure that you've correctly [activated the AXFetchAsSregTransform](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/).