# is it possible to get the email of a user who logs in using open id providers?

Tags: authentication, openid

i want to know if its possible to get the email of the people who are using open id to authenticate to my site [of course with the user knowing that i am getting their email]?
this email will be the user id of the user and i want the user to be able to loggin using any provider and then i will set this email as the user identity.
i need this information in order to design the structure of my site.
i am looking into the following open id providers.

- Gmail
- Yahoo
- Facebook Connect
- Hotmail

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use open social API's...

OpenSocial defines a common API for social applications across multiple websites. With standard JavaScript and HTML, developers can create apps that access a social network's friends and update feeds.

Refer to this link for more:-
http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/

Comment: For Google refer to this question:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301200/openid-trying-to-get-email-address-from-google-op

Answer (score 0):

Who says the OpenID provider has the user's e-mail to give to you? I can get an OpenID identity that's accessed only by my fingerprint.

Comment: i saw somewhere an api for facebook that returns the email of the user and i think google have something like that, it should not be neccessary using open id but maybe an extention or something

Comment: well the 4 providers i listed have your email. but i am not sure that hotmail is an open id provider.